# Connecting Centos VMs to each other for K8s

Tags: linux, networking, centos, kubernetes, kubectl

Im trying to set up kubernetes on my centos VMs using virtualbox. I prefer to use the kubeadm method, so that I can join slave nodes with a join token.

My issue is that I think I am lacking understanding of how to connect my VMs to one another beforehand. This is the resource I am using for the Kubernetes installation: 
https://www.profiq.com/kubernetes-cluster-setup-using-virtual-machines/

When I create VMs and run ifconfig, they all have the same IPs listed, even if they are new VMs and not just a copy of the original. I must be doing something wrong.

Anyway, Im just wondering if anyone would be so kind as to give me some steps to get my VMs talking to each other, just to be sure Im doing it correctly. Im following the article I posted, and can ping each VM from the other, but then ran ifconfig and, since each machine has the same 10.0.2.15 IP, I feel like its just pinging itself and not the master from slave, etc

Answer (score 0):

Did you perform the step after the cloning and before you load kubernetes to change the IP addresses of the 2nd and 3rd VM?

from the instructions you are following, I see:

```
Now create a linked clone machines from kubemaster machines created before. Once you’re done, boot into machine and change following things to match infrastructure:

Set IP address 192.168.99.21 (or 22 for second slave) for host only network.
Set hostname hostnamectl set-hostname kubeslave1 (or kubeslave2 for second slave) Everything else is already configured.
```

Comment: Im new to virtualbox, but I can run hostname -i in each VM and it does show its own respective IP. 
Is there a way for me to give a centos box a custom IP of my choosing that Im not aware of?

Comment: yes, that seems to be what the instructions are counting on but they don't say exactly how - just that you must change the IP for the 2nd and 3rd VM.  I'll spin one up and refresh my memory about how and get back to you!

Comment: Sounds awesome. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I found that when you clone the kubemaster VM to make your kubeslave1 and kubeslave2 VMs, that if you check the "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards" box then each VM gets its own IP.

Comment: (note: I activated host-only and NAT networking when installing and ignored the nmtui step)

Comment: Great, thanks so much. Did you use the 192.168.99... IPs in the hosts config, as well as the host only adapters?

Comment: I used the addresses that got assigned automatically to the host-only ifcs

Comment: Oh, OK. Ive checked the box to reinitialize the MAC address and I still see the 10.0.2.15 IPs for any machine that I clone. Do you think that could be a possible virtualbox issue, or something that Im maybe doing incorrectly? Everything looks the same in ifconfig, and the only way I can get the machines to have different IPs is if I switch the NAT adapter to NET Network. But them my machines still will not talk. So just checking the box to reinitialize MAC address gave you a different IP? Did you create a linked clone?

Comment: Or would it be OK if the IP address stays the same as long as the MAC address changes, maybe?

Comment: The 10.0 duplicate addresses are a NAT interface..  I enabled both NAT and host-only in the settings.  I think if you stop your VMs, open settings for each of them, go to the network tab and add an additional "host-only" ifc, you'll see a 192. address, unique, for each machine in addition to the NAT 10. one - or at least that's what I think I did... kind of a messy process :)

Comment: I was able to give each machine a 192 address by adding a NAT Network adapter. I was able to use nmtui to change the address on the second machine. So I have 192.168.1.1 on master and 192.168.1.2 on the slave. I am, however, unable to ping on machine from the other using those addresses. So Im currently looking into that in hopes that these 192 addresses will be of good use

Comment: But I dont know if a NAT Network adapter, rather than just NAT, is enough for the machines to communicate